# Parsing JSON from tweets

Tags: c#, json, api, twitter, json.net

I am trying to parse a JSON object in C# from Twitter using `JObject` I cannot seem to figure out where the starting point is for the results that I need. For example:

I need to get the following:

- Avatar URL
- Twitter name
- Message

The JSON string looks like the following:

> {"completed_in":0.01,"max_id":297026363595042816,"max_id_str":"297026363595042816","page":1,"query":"UOL01","refresh_url":"?since_id=297026363595042816&q=O1","results":[{"created_at":"Thu, 31 Jan 2013 16:59:38 +0000","from_user":"CarrieLouiseH","from_user_id":252240491,"from_user_id_str":"252240491","from_user_name":"Carrie Haworth","geo":null,"id":297026363595042816,"id_str":"297026363595042816","iso_language_code":"nl","metadata":{"result_type":"recent"},"profile_image_url":"http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1721499350/5680_216695890261_521090261_7945528_588811_n_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1721499350/5680_216695890261_521090261_7945528_588811_n_normal.jpg","source":"<a href="http://twitter.com/">web</a>","text":"Test #01","to_user":null,"to_user_id":0,"to_user_id_str":"0","to_user_name":null}],"results_per_page":15,"since_id":0,"since_id_str":"0"}

My assumption was that if I started at "results" then I could have access to "from_user" etc.. Here is my code (so far):

```
void DownloadStringCompleted(object senders, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            List<TwitterItem> contentList = new List<TwitterItem>();

            JObject ja = JObject.Parse(e.Result);
            int count = 0;

            JToken jUser = ja["results"];

            var name2 = (string)jUser["from_user_name"];
        }catch(Exception e){
         MessageBox.Show("There was an error");
        }
    }
```

But this just seems to catch the Exception. Anyone have any ideas to where I am going wrong?

Comment: Check the exception for more information, especially e.Message...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON you have is incorrect - the `"` of the element results[0]["source"] should be escaped:

```
...,"source":"<a href=\"http://twitter.com/\">web</a>","...
```

Also, `ja["results"]` is an array. You cannot use the string indexer to get its element. You first need to get the element on the desired index, then you can access its `from_user_name` property:

```
JObject ja = JObject.Parse(e.Result);
int count = 0;
JToken jUser = ja["results"][0];
var name2 = (string)jUser["from_user_name"];
```

Comment: Thansks :)! So the `ja["results"][0]` would the `[0]` change depending on the while loop? So would it therefore increment as it goes through it?

Comment: `ja["results"]` is an array. If you want the first element, get `ja["results"][0]`. If you want all elements, enumerate on `ja["results"].Children()`, and you'll get all of them.